# Program using waitFor() not working on linux as it is on windows

Tags: java, linux, thread-safety, synchronized

Hello everyone don't know why  this code works on windows but not on  linux  so if  anyone sees something wrong with this or another way of doing this I would really appreciate some guidance thanks for your time.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(linuxCommand);
int cont=0,retorno=p.waitFor();
try {
     synchronized (this) {
     while (retorno!=0 && conteo<10000){
         retorno=p.waitFor();
         System.out.println("cont++);
     }
    if (retorno == 0) {
        ans = true;
        logger.info("Return Value: " + ans);
    }else{
        ans = false;
        logger.info("Return Value: " + ans);
    }
 }

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Objective**: create *1_Output.txt* from the info contained in *1_Input.txt*,

**MyObjectT** resides in /var/xp/client/a/h/n/test
**MyObjectT** will call several classes in /var/xp/client/a/h/n/clases/z1, and eventually **READ** the content of 1_Output.txt so it can return **ans**(true/false)

**PROBLEM**

- on windows: the flow when to fast it did not wait for the 1_Output.txt file to be created so there was nothing to read, with current code that was solved. (p.waitFor() eventually return 0 and everyone is happy)
- Linux : p.waitFor() never returns 0 the flow ends and nothing

**linuxCommand** is a parsed String that represent a java command to be executed in linux

notice that if I paste this command as it is in the command shell it would run ok with no warning or error . I donw think  **"** play an important role here. linuxCommand->
**/opt/jdk/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java -classpath "/var/xp/client/a/h/n/clases/z1":"/var/xp/client/a/h/n/test" MyObjectT /m:Param21 /f:"/var/xp/client/a/h/n/IOFile/1_Input.txt" /o:"/var/xp/client/a/h/n/IOFile/1_Output.txt"**

so what confuses me is that if use getErrorStream() to track down some errors an I get this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyObjectT 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyObjectT 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: MyObjectT.  Program will exit.
```

any help, its much appreciated thank again

lol Im sorry for the variable name in spanish retorno=return but at the time I translated I did not stop and think about the **return**  ajajjaajajajaj :=)

Comment: Something is wrong in your source.  You have written `return=p.waitFor();`

Comment: This might be related: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t138173-runtime-getruntim-exec-somecmd-problem-with-linux.html

Comment: Your error has something to do with your classpath. Where is MyObjectT located and what is its package hierarchy?

Comment: thank you for your time yeah Iknow the **"return"** but I originally had it in Spanish **retorno** and after abusy day at work...  @DJ thanks for your consideration,in fact I replaced linuxCommand variable for "updatedb" and it worked. The proccess waited for a at least 15 seconds and then returned ans=0 so YES its something about the classpath but what,another interesting thing is if you change the parsing setting partialy to windows so the classpath separator stays **:** like in Linux it will scream with the same stackTrace error like in the above example

Comment: @sarnold I fix the variable name to reflect the original code any hints on classpath issue that DJ was talking about

Comment: @RaYToal yeah definitely that was a Spanish-English Translation issue I have fix it now, do you think I might use something else to makeit work on linux thanks

Comment: @Jesse you need to go back and accept answers to your questions.  Also, read the FAQ. They have some good information.

Comment: Thanks for including the original, failing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things in play, simultaneously. First, you've got multiple programs running -- this one and the one that you're spawning -- and the errors in *that* program are causing troubles here.

First, the `linuxCommand`:

```
/opt/jdk/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java -classpath
"/var/xp/client/a/h/n/clases/z1":"/var/xp/client/a/h/n/test"
MyObjectT /m:Param21 /f:"/var/xp/client/a/h/n/IOFile/1_Input.txt"
/o:"/var/xp/client/a/h/n/IOFile/1_Output.txt"
```

I've arbitrarily line-wrapped it. Depending upon how you've defined this string in your program, you may need to escape all those `"` marks in this string. (If you just print this using `System.out.println()`, what does it look like?)

Probably the better approach is to use a [slightly different form of `exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29), one that takes an array of strings instead of a single string. This way you can break the parameters as the program *requires* without worrying about proper shell quoting. It'd look something like this (untested) chunk:

```
String linuxCommand[] = {"/opt/jdk/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java",
                         "-classpath",
                         "/var/xp/client/a/h/n/clases/z1:/var/xp/client/a/h/n/test",
                         "MyObjectT",
                         "/m:Param21",
                         "/f:/var/xp/client/a/h/n/IOFile/1_Input.txt",
                         "/o:/var/xp/client/a/h/n/IOFile/1_Output.txt"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(linuxCommand);
```

You did say you've run this command by hand in a shell to confirm it works, but those `/i`, `/o`, etc. feel *very* awkward on a Unix-alike platform. Are you *confident* that format works as expected on Linux?

Comment: well thank you so much for your answer and yes is definitively the **" "** I had to remove every single one of them and re run the command everything worked alright apparently Linux doesn't like quotes I fixed on Friday and I was thinking about the rate thing... anyways thats the answer Linux with exec(NO QUOTES COMMAND..)  =0) THANKS  AGAIN SARNOLD